# Upload file to server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

How to make request from retrofit android if the request to server looks like in the image.
[image]

Comment: have you tried so far?  you may upload an image, video easily by retrofit.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried searching before asking? You have to do that, you know, right?

Comment: `@Multipart
    @POST("upload-evidence")
    Call<UploadEvidenceResponse> uploadEvidence(@Header("token") String token,
                                                @Part("order_id") RequestBody order_id,
                                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file);`

code above is request in interface declaration, however i get respose: field evedence_img[] is required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could search about this before posting, quite sure you could have found something already, but..

```
@Multipart
@POST(RestClient.UPDATE_USER_PICTURE)
Call<BooleanResponse> updateUserPicture(@Part MultipartBody.Part picture, @Part("picture") RequestBody file);
```

Above part is the retrofit interface method that you'll use

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), loadImageFile);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", loadImageFile.getName(), reqFile);
RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), loadImageFile.getName());

RestClient.getApi().updateUserPicture(filePart, filename).enqueue(new Callback<BooleanResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BooleanResponse> call, Response<BooleanResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 200){
                Toast.makeText(CompleteProfile.this, "Picture updated successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BooleanResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CompleteProfile.this, "Request failed !" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "-=onFailure=-\n" + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am using form-urlencoded, if i using multipart, the reponse said: field evidence_img[] is required.